# Rails 3. Why is my nested record deleted when I go to the Edit page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, nested, has-one

Every company is supposed to have one CompanyContact. My Company form has fields for company contacts. When I update the Company and add a new company contact, it works fine, because in the show page for company, it does show the new company contact. But when I click the Edit link that takes me to the Edit page (note: I don't even click the update button yet), in the Edit Company form where the companycontact is supposed to be is blank. So i check the logs and the companycontact was deleted.

`DELETE FROM "company_contacts" WHERE "company_contacts"."id" = ?  [["id", 4]]`

I'm confused because I haven't called any delete action.

```
----------------------------------------
company.rb
has_one :company_contact, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :company_contact

----------------------------------------
company_contact.rb
belongs_to :company

----------------------------------------
companies_controller.rb
def new
  @company = Company.new
  company_contact = @company.build_company_contact
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @company }
  end
end

def edit
  @company = Company.find(params[:id])
  company_contact = @company.build_company_contact
end
```

Comment: I'm guessing that `@company.build_company_contact` deletes the associated record if it exists for a `has_one` relationship. I can see this being justifiable, but a bit unexpected.

Comment: None of the records is ever saved in db in provided code, so I cannot see how deletion can be justified

Comment: @UncleGene I think it's wrong to assume that the code he posted tells the whole story. He never said anything about the records not getting saved by the create action. Therefore, I'm operating on the assumption that he's hitting the edit action for records that look as we should expect them to.

Answer (score 2):

In your edit action you're building a company contact for your company, but your company has only one company contact. Check for existence before building a new one:

```
company_contact = @company.company_contact || @company.build_company_contact
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this in the ActiveRecord source, which confirms the suspicion I commented on above (comments in the code below are mine):

```
class HasOneAssociation < SingularAssociation #:nodoc:
  def replace(record, save = true)
    raise_on_type_mismatch(record) if record
    load_target

    reflection.klass.transaction do
      # !!!
      # This is where your record is getting deleted
      # !!!
      if target && target != record
        remove_target!(options[:dependent]) unless target.destroyed?
      end

      if record
        set_owner_attributes(record)
        set_inverse_instance(record)

        if owner.persisted? && save && !record.save
          nullify_owner_attributes(record)
          set_owner_attributes(target) if target
          raise RecordNotSaved, "Failed to save the new associated #{reflection.name}."
        end
      end
    end

    self.target = record
  end
...
```

This `replace` method appears to be called whenever `record.build_association` is used.

Your `edit` action shouldn't build the associated record if one already exists.